# Past perfect really needed

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

> Person A: Did they eventually  sign to a booking agency?
>   Person B: Yes, but after I had stopped managing them

I just would like to know if past simple would be possible and is past perfect here to explain that the band sign to a booking agency because but they did not have a manager to establish a strong link between them

Comment: You sre correct. The past perfect is not really needed here. The past simple does the job.

Answer (score 4):

Past simple would be possible in this sentence:

> Person A: Did they eventually sign to a booking agency?
>   Person B: Yes, but after I stopped managing them.

**After** strongly defines the relationship between the two events, so it is not necessary to alter the tense to past perfect to define the order.

**Before** also strongly defines the relationship between the two events. You  only need to use past perfect with words like **when**: without past perfect, the two events happened at the same time: with past perfect, one is pushed backwards before the other.

> They signed to a booking agency when I stopped managing them - *simultaneous*
>   They signed to a booking agency when I **had** stopped managing them - *had stopped is before signed*
>   They **had** signed to a booking agency when I stopped managing them - *had signed is before stopped*

Note that I have kept the clauses in the same order in the three examples: normally the oldest clause would come first, so the clauses would be reversed in the second example.

Comment: I think this answer is better than the one I've cited as a duplicate (it's short and to the point), but the general principle is usually to keep the *older* question open, so I feel kinda forced into a position I don't fully endorse. I suspect there might be quite a few "Should I use Past Perfect here?" questions where all we actually need to do is drum into learners that if the context (through words like ***before, after***, or whatever) clearly establishes temporal sequence, native speakers will tend to grab the opportunity to use a simpler verb tense.